# Row Split exporting to Excel with JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, dynamic-jasper

i was trying to export multiple lines to an excel using DynamicJasper and JasperReports.

Everything works fine but, when i try to export to excel and the excel has more than one sheet i get rows with splitted content like this.

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

I have tried Stretching.RELATIVE_TO_BAND_HEIGHT), isStretchWithOverflow(),....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i fixed it

setAllowDetailSplit to false in the DynamicReport